# How to get "Host:" header from HttpContext (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to server parts of my application from different domains.
To be precise I have a sub section of the site that should be served from a region specific domain. For example:

- /fr/* should be served from www.domain.fr
- /uk/* should be serverd from www.domain.co.uk
  and so on.

I'd like to make a route entry that will redirect the request with wrong domain to the correct domain. But I don't know how to access http header information form HttpContext.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
string requestedDomain = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
string requestScheme = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme;
string requestQueryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"];
string requestUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["URL"];
```

Comment: HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] is what i was looking for. Thx

Answer (score 7):

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host`

Comment: HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];  -- done the trick

Comment: It doesn't work, It always returns the same value. (ie. It returns localhost even if I access the site using 127.0.0.1 or "Anyotherdomain or ip address")

Comment: `Reqiest.Url.Host` will only have the Host header value if the app setting "aspnet:UseHostHeaderForRequestUrl" has the value of "true" (the default is "false").

Answer (score 5):

I think you want Request.Headers["host"]

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you want to know from the host who sent de request, so I used this

```
 stsring _Host = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"];
```