# How do I securely get the domain name of the running ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, security, http, iis

I’ve encountered some issues with spoofing of the Host value in HTTP transactions.  In order to close security holes related to these types of attacks, I need to securely detect what the domain of the running ASP.NET site.  Unfortunately, [all of the references I find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638669/how-to-get-host-header-from-httpcontext-asp-net) suggest you use `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]` or `Request.Url.Host`.  By submitting invalid HTTP packets, I have been able to set invalid host values and observer the behavior they're causing with both function calls.  The behavior I'm seeing is different depending on the type of .NET environment I use.

In IIS 6, the injected value always shows up, no matter if I access the request directly in an MVC Controller action, or in a location that requires me to access the values through `HttpContext.Current.Request`.

In the Visual Studio 2012 ASP.Net Development Server, I only see the injected values in library code we deployed to the project through a NuGet package.  In the NuGet package I have to use the `HttpContext.Current` since the code runs outside of the scope of the web application.  When I stay within the scope of the web application's namespace, even if I have to call the `HttpContext.Current`, it will provide the correct unspoofed value.

For all of this testing, I have been using ASP.NET 4.0.  Has this behavior changed in ASP.NET 4.5 and IIS 8?  Is there a way to securely get the domain name?  It is also possible to do the [same attack against PHP](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host), but [Apache has a way that can prevent these types of attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name/2297421#2297421).  Does IIS?

Example of the code I've been having problems with:

```
string siteName1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
string siteName2 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
```

Example of an invalid HTTP Packet:

```
GET:  https://sampledomain.com/Items/Index
Host: fakedomain
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

I've done my testing with the Firefox extension [Live HTTP headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) which has allowed me to quickly record and replay my requests to the web server.

Comment: I'm not an expert on security, but isn't the `Host:` property for the client to determine, to tell the HTTP server which virtual host at a given IP it was trying to reach? I'm surprised that the servers themselves don't provide a way to reject any requests for a nonexistent vhost for any HTTP/1.1 request that uses that header.

Comment: I don't know why they webserver doesn't automatically block junk requests like this.  Apparently with a fully qualified domain name in the get request, IIS doesn't use the host value, but passes it on to the application layer.

Comment: IIS does use the host value and it does block the request... you just need to setup your host headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS you could setup the site's bindings so that it only gets requests matching particular host header value(s).

That way if someone tries to spoof the host header value, your website won't even see the request.

Not exactly an answer to your question, but possibly an solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean by "securely", but the entire point of the Host header is to allow the browser to specify the host it intended to talk to.

[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) has a few things to say about the `Request-URI` and `Host` header:

> To allow for transition to `absoluteURI`s in all requests in future
> versions of HTTP, all HTTP/1.1 servers MUST accept the `absoluteURI`
> form in requests, even though HTTP/1.1 clients will only generate
> them in requests to proxies.

> ...

> The most common form of `Request-URI` is that used to identify a
> resource on an origin server or gateway. In this case the absolute
> path of the URI MUST be transmitted (see section 3.2.1, `abs_path`) as
> the `Request-URI`, and the network location of the URI (authority) MUST
> be transmitted in a `Host` header field.

> ...

> 1. If `Request-URI` is an `absoluteURI`, the host is part of the
>    `Request-URI`. Any `Host` header field value in the request MUST be
>    ignored.

> ...

> The `Host` field value MUST represent
> the naming authority of the origin server or gateway given by the
> original URL. This allows the origin server or gateway to
> differentiate between internally-ambiguous URLs, such as the root "/"
> URL of a server for multiple host names on a single IP address.

> ...

> A client MUST include a `Host` header field in all HTTP/1.1 request
> messages. If the requested URI does not include an Internet host name for the service being requested, then the `Host` header field MUST
> be given with an empty value.

> ...

> The requirements that clients and servers support the `Host` request-
> header, report an error if the `Host` request-header (section 14.23) is
> missing from an HTTP/1.1 request, and accept absolute URIs (section
> 5.1.2) are among the most important changes defined by this
> specification.

> ...

> - Both clients and servers MUST support the `Host` request-header.

- A client that sends an HTTP/1.1 request MUST send a `Host` header.
- Servers MUST report a 400 (Bad Request) error if an HTTP/1.1
  request does not include a `Host` request-header.
- Servers MUST accept absolute URIs.

In summary, while a conforming HTTP client cannot send the request

```
GET https://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: fakedomain.invalid
```

to an origin server, an HTTP/1.1 server is **required** to accept it, use `example.com` as the host, and "ignore" the `Host` header. `Request.Url.Host` should definitely be `example.com`; if not it's a bug in IIS. I'm less certain about `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]`, but a reasonable interpretation of "ignoring" the host header would be to rewrite it to say `example.com`.

(Incidentally, the two other servers I've just tested don't follow the spec either: Apache 2.4.3 assumes that a request to an `absoluteURI` must be one to a proxy and denies it on that basis, while lighttpd 1.4.28 allows `GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1` without a `Host` header.)