# How to fix issue when entering www.sitename.com/ROBOTS.TXT in URL only refreshes the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, robots.txt

I have a site that's about to be taken down in month's time. What I need to do is place a robots.txt to prevent the search engine from indexing it any longer. However, after I placed the file on the root of the solution in the web server, and tried to check if I can access it by typing www.sitename.com/robots.txt, it just refreshes the screen or perhaps just returns to the home page. My application is running in MVC 3.

Things I've already tried:

1. Added modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" in web.config
2. Used Dynamic Robots.Txt using IHttpHandler and Controller/Action approach (based on this link [robots.txt file for different domains of same site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033779/robots-txt-file-for-different-domains-of-same-site/17037935))
3. Played around with MIME Types (removed .txt and back)

I am expecting to see the contents of the robots.txt file same as when I access a css file or js file just by appending the file name in the URL.