# Asp and WebClient: How to get dynamically actual host?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I want to get datas from an html file on my asp webserver, in Javascript to get actual host we can use the following:

```
~/mydatas.php
```

It gives on localhost: "http://localhost/mydatas.php"

I want the same thing but in C# can you help me?

Thanks you.

Comment: You can use use ~/mydatas.aspx as well

Comment: I ve already try this but it don't works on localhost.

Comment: Check this question may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211973/get-host-domain-from-url/14212007#14212007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also search in stackoverflow and you will find a lot of answered question which had the same problematic than you. Like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638669/how-to-get-host-header-from-httpcontext-asp-net)

Hopes it will help you !

Edit : You can use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

It will give you the URL of your web page.

Comment: @userfloflo I just edited my answer with respect of your counterclaim

Answer (score 0):

I've already try

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
```

which gives on localhost

> :\windows\system32\inetsrv\localhost

...